# ios opengl 3.0 does not compile version

Tags: ios, xcode5, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying out opengl 3.0 in xcode 5

this is how I compile the shader

```
*shader = glCreateShader(type);
glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
glCompileShader(*shader);
```

this is my shader

```
#version 140
attribute vec4 position; 
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 colorVarying;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;
out int rowIndex;
out int colIndex;

void main(void) { 
    colorVarying = color;
    gl_Position = position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

i try:

```
glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
```

returns 235, which is expected. but i get

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '140' is not supported
```

from the compile log, I have tried many version numbers and only 100 worked. then i get

```
Invalid qualifiers 'out' in global variable context
```

what's wrong? I am running this on the iphone 4 64bit simulator, on my mac air with Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB graphics

Comment: AFAIK the graphics adapter on the Mac pretty much does not play any role as Apple implemented an abstraction layer that emulates the GL/ES hardware of the device (pure software) within the simulator - in other words, the GL/ES calls do not get straight to the device driver of your Mac.

Comment: Have you tried _#version 300 es_ and replacing _attribute_ with _in_ and _varying_ with _out_?

Comment: @Till in other words, I have to try it on the device itself?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine #version 300 gives me "syntax error #version" and all 'in's and 'out's throw the same error as above

Comment: @tzi that is not what I meant to say. But generally you should indeed try the device instead of the simulator, especially when it comes to OpenGL/ES development. What I meant to say is that the simulator is using a piece of software that tries to simulate the OpenGL/ES implementation of an iOS device. As such, it does not depend on the Mac hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused about what you're trying to do. You're saying you want to use OpenGL 3.0, yet you have tagged the question for OpenGL ES 3.0. Since you're talking about iPhone simulator, I'll assume you want to use OpenGL ES 3.0. You should note that on Apple mobile devices, only iPhone 5S has OpenGL ES 3.0-capable GPU. I don't know how well ES 3.0 works in the simulator - at least you should try the iPhone 5S simulator if there is such a thing available.

As for your shader, it looks like a merry mix of different language versions. First, for OpenGL ES 3.0 you need  `#version 300 es`. The only other allowed version in OpenGL ES is `#version 100` for ES 2.0. I don't know why you're trying `#version 140` since it's only for (desktop) OpenGL 3.1. I don't know why you are expecting and getting 235 from GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION? As per the spec, it should return `OpenGL ES GLSL ES N.M ...`, where N is major and M minor language version number.

Then, as noted by SurvivalMachine, you need to replace your `varying`s with `out` and `attribute`s with `in`.

Comment: my bad. I did mean opengl ES 3.0. and getting 235 from GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION is also caused by a bug in my code. #version 300 es compiled fine for me in the 64-bit iphone simulator. thanks!

Comment: "As per the spec, it should return OpenGL ES GLSL ES N.M ...," - Which spec?